# Export Firebase data to file

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, export

I'm working on an app built using Firebase on Android. The application is for keeping track of in-patients currently under our care. Our team can enter progress notes for each patient, and add tasks needed yo be performed for each patient, and mark them when they're done. I have all that done, however, I need to add one more option, where I can select a patient, and export the current view (with all the many-to-one data associated with the main record) to an external file (editable file), so we may use it to write his/her final report and summary. I've searched online, and found many recommending to export the view as a bitmap, then to pdf ... but that makes the document un-editable .. If someone has any ideas, or can point me to the right direction, I'd be grateful. The final format is not really an issue ... pdf, txt, doc, html .... I guess it doesn't really matter, as long as the data can be exported as it is in the current view (ordered and making sense), and can be edited.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I once made an app with the option to export data to a txt file on the device storage. Here's the method I used:

```
public void exportTxt(String text){
        if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equalsIgnoreCase("mounted"))//Check if Device Storage is present
        {
            try {
                File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyAppFolder");//You might want to change this to the name of your app. (This is a folder that will be created to store all of your txt files)
                if (!root.exists()) {
                    root.mkdirs();
                }
                File myTxt = new File(root, "filename.txt"); //You might want to change the filename
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(myTxt);
                writer.append(text);//Writing the text
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                Toast.makeText(this, "File exported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error: "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else
                Toast.makeText(this, "Can't access device storage!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Don't forget to add this permission to your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

So in order to use this method, all you need to do is group all of your currentView data on a single String and pass it as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you !! I haven't tried it yet, but it looks like I can manage it from here ... will let u know how it goes ... but thanks anyway ... for the time being, I'll consider this question "answered" :)